# Is there a way to easily compare driver versions between computer A and computer B?

Tags: windows, drivers, powershell, script, software-rec

I have a gold standard machine that contains all the correct drivers and I want to know if there is an easy way to compare the driver version between computer A and computer B (both with identical hardware).

I've had a look online and can see there are others that have had a stab at this ([see here](https://www.systanddeploy.com/2017/06/powershell-module-compare-2-computer.html)), but they are very outdated and old so cannot use. Is there a relatively up-to-date way to achieve this? The linked article is for a PSGallery module "[CompareComputer](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/comparecomputer/1.0.0.0)" that flags driver differences between A and B, and this is exactly what I'm trying to find.

Looking at device manager there are a lot of drivers to right-click compare when remoting into computer A and B

[image]

I'm struggling to find a scripting or third party software solution that points me in the right direction. Is anyone able to recommend anything that can help?

Comment: Can you not just run `Get-WmiObject Win32_PnPSignedDriver | Select DeviceName,DriverVersion` on both machines, direct the output to a CSV, then compare in Excel?

Comment: Hi Spikey, yes indeed and thank you for the code sample there. However, it would be great to have something a little more purpose made for the job. Specifically having the drivers that are mismatch at least colour coded or flagged in some way.

Comment: Sure, many things exist, but often there is just your unique stuff. Based on what you ask for, then no. You have to write this yourself. Cmdltets and DOS executables exist for such use cases, as '@harrymc' suggests.  As for all the colonizing stuff you are asking for, then that too is a no. Again, you have to write that in yourself, even if using what '@harrymc' is prudently suggesting. As per your comment, you are asking folks to write a complete answer for you. You have yet to show us what you've tried where we can evaluate and address/assist where we can.

Comment: Hi Postanote, i certainly am not asking anyone to write any scripts here. I didn't think it would be as unique a request to even require that. I'm hoping there's a third party software solution out there that can do the job. I'm even willing to go for paid software. Just seems like this is the sort of thing others would have wanted in the past. Amazed it doesn't already exist which is why I reached out for suggestions here.

Answer (score 2):

You may create a list of all drivers in PowerShell using the command:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_PnPSignedDriver | Select Description,DeviceName,DriverVersion
```

You may use
[Sort-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object?view=powershell-7.3)
to sort the list and write it out to a text file.

To compare two lists, use any text compare program, such as `WinDiff`
or `WinMerge` or other.